# How to get specific data from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, extract

So I have a json file. Where I load it as json file in python and I try to get the items from the dictionary. I can access the 'sha' the 'author' and get all of its components but how can I access just the 'message', 'name', and 'date' ?

I try this code to access the 'messages' but I get a key error:

```
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(str(type(data))) # class <dict>
    for p in data['commits']:
        print(p['message'])
```

**My file Looks like this: (It contains more than one commit messages):**

```
{

   "commits":[  
      {  
         "sha":"exampleSHA",
         "node_id":"exampleID",
         "commit":{  
            "author":{  
               "name":"example",
               "email":"example@example.se",
               "date":"2015-09-07T22:06:51Z"
            },
            "committer":{  
               "name":"example",
               "email":"example@example.se",
               "date":"2015-09-07T22:06:51Z"
            },
            "message":"Added LaTex template and instructions",
            "tree":{  
               "sha":"examplesha",
               "url":"http://example.url"
            },
         "parents":[]
      }}
   ]
}
```

There are many 'messages' that I want to get all of them from the dict.

The result would be this:

```
AuthorName   Message                                Date
example      Added LaTex template and instructions  2013-07-08T20:16:51Z
example2     Message2                               2015-09-07T22:06:51Z
....         ....                                   .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
data = json.load(json_file)
print(str(type(data))) # class <dict>
for p in data['commits']:
    print(p['commit']['message'])
```

`message` field is nested inside `commit` field.

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you :D ill accept the answer as right in 10'